# Xcode 9 - show the line that threw the exception

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 9.3. I was using Xcode 9.2.

In 9.2, when an exception occurred, the debugger showed the line that caused the exception in the editor area, and I would see the variables and their values, plus the console in the debug area.

I did not change anything, and yet, now, I get the stack trace in the editor area. Given that the error is a simple "found nil when unwrapping a variable" and is an explicit error in a single line of code, the stack trace is next to useless in finding this. In fact, in looking at the stack trace and variables, the only variable that is nil is not a variable that is created within the method that the stack highlights.

Since then, I have enabled Zombies. I have had to re-add an All Exceptions break point (why does it forget these between versions is a whole other question) set to "on Throw".
I have deleted Derived Data, cleans the build, restarted Xcode, restarted the Mac and made various rude gestures to my screen. The last helped a bit, however the rest achieved nothing.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your stack trace? Would provide more detail to debug.

Comment: The question is not about the stack trace. I can find these problems eventually. This question is regarding getting Xcode 9.3 to open the swift file containing the faulty line and highlighting that line.